# "Cannot find symbol" errors in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, maven

I work on a school project using NetBeans 7, Maven and the NetBeans Platform. The project has been created using the "Maven/POM Project" project template. It is a multi-tiered "enterprise" application that uses several modules (model, integration, bussiness, presentation, the rich client application itself and couple of others).

There are dependencies between these modules (but no circular dependencies). The problem is, either Maven, or NetBeans, keep getting confused. There are several types of problems which appear semmingly without any trigger. I have to keep recompiling the modules, closing and re-opening NetBeans, clearing NetBeans cache, removing and readding the dependencies and so on to *temporarily* remove the issues. I keep having these problems with two different installations of NetBeans on Windows XP SP3 and Mac OS X.

The symptoms are:

1) Sometimes NetBeans decides that none of the classes imported from another module exist (and I get the `cannot find symbol` errors. This happens repeatedly, sometimes to modules I have succesfully compiled seconds ago. Most of the time, recompiling the dependency doesn't help. The necessary dependencies are declared in the POM, the jar files exist, and if I expand them in the project view, I can see the classes in question.

2) Sometimes NetBeans decides that a method of an imported class doesn't actually throw an exception it declares to throw. Since the calls to such methods are usually surrounded by `try` blocks, NetBeans display error with the message `a.package.SomeException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`. If I don't remove the try block, the module doesn't compile because of NetBeans. If do remove the block, the module doesn't compile because of Maven (Maven, for some reason, *can* see the exception, and complains that it's not caught). This also happens repeatedly, I am not quite sure how to reliably fix this one.

At this point, the problems with Maven and NetBeans are so bad I cannot actually work on the project. If I didn't have to use NetBeans and Maven, I would have been back to vim and Makefiles by now. Does anyone at least recognize these problems?

**EDIT:** I've submitted the project, got 30 out of 20 points for it for some extra work I've done on it, and until it leaves the alpha stage, I hope to never have to work with NetBeans again.

Comment: Try to use maven on command line for your projects, outside of netbeans, to see if problems come from netbeans or maven.

Comment: I just upgraded to NetBeans 7.1. Right now, Maven compiles everything without problems, but NetBeans still shows **cannot find symbol** in some of the files.

Comment: I would just like to know how these things even happen. How is it possible there is this major bug in this piece of... software that makes it pretty much unusable and everyone pretends it doesn't exist?

Comment: In netbeans, are you sure your project is a maven project ? (-> in project window, the project logo node is a cup with a little "m" on top left).

Comment: It is maven project alright, except it's a NetBeans Platform application using maven, so the logo of the module container looks like letters "ma" and the logos of the individual modules look like puzzle pieces with "m" in the corner.

Answer (score 2):

I had a `is never thrown` masking a `cannot find symbol`in a multi-module maven project in Netbeans 7.0.0

The symbol in question was a class in another module under my maven master project.

I refactor/renamed the class that wasn't being found - this fixed the issue.  I then renamed it back - the issue remained fixed.

Not ideal by any means, but figured I'd share.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be my case, but it may be useful to someone else, so thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Multi-module project where dependency was flagged as missing (cannot find symbol) even though it was there. Annoying bug. Renaming and rebuilding helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with netbeans flagging error '...Exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement'
Project would build ok, but error messages would not go away.
Finally fixed it by quitting and reopening netbeans.

I'm on a mac, and the close button doesn't actually close netbeans, needed to do a full quit.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dependency, building (and getting compilation errors), then re-adding it (either manually, from pom.xml, or from the interface) helped me. But I do agree this is a major bug.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this once with NetBeans 8.0.2. the issue was clearly related to project lombok but i have no idea why it happened. i installed maven and did 'mvn clean install' on each of my projects and it seemed to clear up the issue. NetBeans started working again after that.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple projects, be careful with netbeans option of compile on save, if some of your dependencies have turned on this option the compilation of your main project will fail, disable automatic compile on save, recompile dependencies (Clean and build) and you should be fine.